# Is posix_fadvice / POSIX_FADV_DONTNEED functional in Linux?

Tags: linux, files, cache

If I am doing once only scanning across big files then do I need to worry about impact on the page cache or does the OS take care to avoid my scan causing pointless churn in the page cache.  I want to avoid impacting other processes that may be benefiting from the page cache.

I considered using `POSIX_FADV_DONTNEED` however I am seeing conflicting advice on whether `posix_fadvice` and `POSIX_FADV_DONTNEED` does anything on Linux.

Can someone clarify, thanks.

Comment: I'd do this by opening the file `O_DIRECT`.

Answer (score 1):

`POSIX_FADV_DONTNEED` is taken into account on Linux; see [`mm/fadvise.c`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/fadvise.c#L117) in the kernel source. Every time you call `posix_fadvise()` with `POSIX_FADV_DONTNEED`, any corresponding page cache is drained.

As [jthill](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/18837/jthill) mentioned, a better approach to minimise the impact of I/O on the page cache would be to open the files with `O_DIRECT`.

Comment: However some file-systems don't support the `O_DIRECT` flag, for example squashfs, iso9660, etc.